# Delete rows until cell = "Total"

Tags: vba, excel, row

I would like to with this macro delete all cells after last empty row until the line where in column "E" is "Total"

I've tried this, but there is error on loop line:

```
    Sub delete()

    Dim r As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
        Dim c As Range
    Dim i As Long
        i = lastRow + 1

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
       End With
    Do
    Set r = Range("B" & i)
        If Len(r) = 0 Then r.EntireRow.delete
    i = i + 1

    Loop Until Cells(i, 5).Value = "Total"

    End Sub
```

And here is the example how my table look like:

[image: Sheet example]

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: sorry, I've forgot to add something - now it is working but the problem is that it will delete only first 3 rows and then stop working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use something like the following which will continue through all cells until `E&i` = total:

```
Public Sub Delete()

Dim i As Long

i = 2 'Start from row 2

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Do Until .Range("E" & i).Value = "Total"
        If .Range("B" & i).Value = vbNullString Then
            .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            i = i + 1 'Only increment if the row hasn't been deleted to prevent skipping rows
        End If
    Loop

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: No problems. I've amended it slightly by adding `Applcation.ScreenUpdating = False` which should yield a performance bonus.